# Pegar valor de uma propriedade do application.properties - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Sou iniciante em Spring Boot. 
Eu tenho um projeto em Spring Boot q tem um `application.properties` e la dentro tem uma propriedade com um valor (`spring.datasource.username=user`) e eu quero pegar esse valor em uma classe java minha, vou usar este valor para fazer a conexao com o banco em jdbc, mas nn consigo pegar o valor, ele sempre vem nulo, procurei na internet e achei muitos exemplos utilizando algo do tipo:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;
```

ou

```
@Value("#{environment['spring.datasource.username']}")
private String username;
```

mas os dois casos a minha propriedade username fica sempre nula. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Edit 1:

Em vermelho esta a classe que eu quero que receba o valor da propriedade `spring.datasource.username` que esta no `application.properties`;

Em amarelo esta o arquivo `application.properties`

[image: Hierarquia do projeto]

Comment: A classe é um bean do Spring, ou seja, está anotada com `@Component`, `@Service`?

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o conteúdo do teu arquivo application.properties, a imagem da estrutura do projeto para vermos onde está esse arquivo e o conteúdo da classe que recupera a propriedade.

Comment: Em qual diretório está o arquivo application.properties?

Comment: Seria interessante postar o repositório no git, daí ficaria mais fácil de vermos a organização de diretórios.
Porém, o application.properties já fornece essa conexão com o banco. Não existe uma necessidade de fazer isso via código Java

Comment: 1° A classe em questão nn esta anotada nem com @Bean e nem com @Component mas vou testar isso agr;

2° O arquivo `application.properties` nn tem nenhum código apenas aquele q eu falei na pergunta;

3° O arquivo `application.properties` esta num diretorio `resources`;

4° Infelizmente nn posso postar o repositorio no git deste projeto;

4.5° Eu estou fazendo a conexão com o banco com `JDBC` puro int estou fazendo via codigo java, em uma classe `ConnectionFactory` e tals;

Comment: @StatelessDev eu tentei adicionar as anotações e tbm nn deu em nada, alguem tem alguma ideia de como posso recuperar um valor de uma propriedade do `application.properties`?

Comment: @Bruno seguinte, o properties esta acessivel por qualquer bean, porem, ele deve ser escaneado pelo Bean primário, vc pode fazer isso via construtor de alguma classe, e criar um bean da classe que vc precisa

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa eu nn consegui entender 100% do seu comentario, pode me explicar mais, tipo, o que é o Bean "primario" e como escanear o properties nele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de mta pesquisa, apesar de ngm aqi me dar a resposta, eu consegui achar, e vou responder aqi pra caso alguma outra pessoa tenha esse problema, a classe ficou assim:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource") //aqi no prefix eh pra colocar qual o caminho q ta as propriedades
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String url;
    private String driver_class_name;

    //getters e setters
}
```

Se vc criar os seus atributos com o msmo nome dos atributos q vc colocou o valor la no arquivo `.properties` o Spring msmo ja conecta eles por baixo dos panos, ae é só usar os getters pra pegar os valores. E se quiser usar em outra classe é só criar uma propriedade la assim:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connection;
```

e usar essa propriedade para pegar os valores.

É isso, vlw flw!

Answer (score -1):

Depois de muita luta esse foi o post que me ajudou. estava ocultando uma senha via application.properties
imdb.apikey = minha-chave

e na classe não estava aceitando

@Service
public class ImDbApiClient {

```
@Value("${imdb.apiKey}")
private String apiKey;
```

...

acrescentando o @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "imdb")
como no exemplo funcionou. Só que tive que colocar o @Value conforme acima.